# AS3 FLASH PLAYING CARD ARRANGE HORIZONTALLY AND GROUP IN SETS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am on a flash card game, in which there are 13 playing cards similar to rummy.

1)The player has to arrange the 13 cards in sets by usign drag and drop.

For example if the cards are KQJ , he will pick J and place it before K to form JQK or he can pick Q and place after J and pick K and place after J to form JQK . The thing is arranging

2)He has to form groups. In Forming groups I have to separate groups with little space like "JQK"  "KQA"

Please help. How to achieve these two things in Flash AS3.

Comment: I have 13 cards randomly placed on the stage, drag is also working, but how to drop it between the cards to arrange? http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/open-source/dynamic-stacking, the arranging is like shown in this link, but how to do it without tweenlite?

Comment: http://www.mathplayground.com/make_24.html, this game also has arranging facility, someone please explain how to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to script this out for you as I know Stack likes but If you just want some direction and your coding knowledge is up for it this may help you enough.You could keep all placed down cards in an array then, when you release (onDrop) a new card, loop through the x positions of each array item to check where in the array the newly dropped card fits, then add to the array and redraw screen from the newly updated array. Different arrays for different groups.

Comment: @InkeyDollarDan, I have updated the array after drag, now how to redraw the screen, I am new to as3 , is there any command or by looping?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to code this out. It would help if you posted your code. It would be good if you draw your cards on screen from arrays from the start, then you would just call the method each time. Something that loops through the array (a for loop) and positions them at whatever y pos you specify and spaced intervals (perhaps 1.5x the cards width for example) along the x. For something like this I would have the card's registration points centered.